# Python.Проверка наличия ошибки в функции

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, try-catch, typedef

Я создаю функцию, которая по фамилии человека берёт информацию про человека из словаря и вывод её, казалось бы всё хорошо идёт, но когда идёт попытка узнать несуществующую Фамилию - прилетает KeyError. Есть ли возможность проигнорировать его не просто return'ом в конце функции, а что бы функция вернула надпись мол "не так задали информацию" и не сломала ничего.

```
        ju = vk_session.method('messages.getConversationMembers',{'peer_id': 2000000001,'fields': 'status,city,personal,sex'}) 
    # gpid = {item.get('last_name'): item.get('id') for item in ju['profiles']} # id человека 
    gba = {item.get('last_name'): item.get('is_closed') for item in ju['profiles']} # Открыт ли профиль 
    gst = {item.get('last_name'): item.get('status') for item in ju['profiles']} # Статус 
    gci = {item.get('last_name'): item.get('city').get('title') for item in ju['profiles'] if 'city' in item} # Город 
    gpe = {item.get('last_name'): item.get('personal') for item in ju['profiles']} # Перс. инфа 
    gn = {item.get('last_name'): item.get('first_name') for item in ju['profiles']} # Имя 
    gsp = {item.get('last_name'): item.get('sex') for item in ju['profiles']} #Пол человека
```

Вот так я получаю информацию по словарю и потом начинаю её обрабатывать вот так:

```
 t2=('Живёт в городе: ' + gci[fam])

        if gpe[fam]['alcohol'] == 0: 
            t3 = ('Алкоголь: не указано')
        if gpe[fam]['alcohol'] == 1: 
            t3 = ('Алкоголь: жесть как не любит') 
        elif gpe[fam]['alcohol'] == 2: 
            t3 = ('Алкоголь: не любит') 
        elif gpe[fam]['alcohol'] == 3: 
            t3 = ('Алкоголь: в целом ок') 
        elif gpe[fam]['alcohol'] == 4: 
            t3 = ('Алкоголь: всё равно') 
        elif gpe[fam]['alcohol'] == 5: 
            t3 = ('Алкоголь: любит') 





        if gpe[fam]['smoking'] == 1: 
            t4 = ('Курение: жесть как не любит') 
        elif gpe[fam]['smoking'] == 2: 
            t4 = ('Курение: не любит') 
        elif gpe[fam]['smoking'] == 3: 
            t4 = ('Курение: в целом ок') 
        elif gpe[fam]['smoking'] == 4: 
            t4 = ('Курение: всё равно') 
        elif gpe[fam]['smoking'] == 5: 
            t4 = ('Курение: любит') 





        if gpe[fam]['life_main'] == 0: 
            t5 = ('Возникла проблема в Фамилии или Главное в жизни не указано') 
        elif gpe[fam]['life_main'] == 1: 
            t5 = ('Главное в жизни: семья и дети') 
        elif gpe[fam]['life_main'] == 2:
```

У меня вышло это реализовать с огромным количеством try except и оно заработало криво, есть ли возможность сделать всё это лаконичнее.
Была конечно идея написать что-то вроде if ошибка вылезла: print('Вы не так ввели') но не знаю как это сделать и нужно ли именно так делать

Оочень прошу помощи[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте не [] (`gpe[fam]`), а `person = gpe.get(fam)`, если нужной фамилии не будет, то эта конструкция вернет None. Далее сделаете `if person is None` и вернете строку из функции какую вам нужно.

А чтобы не делать такие громоздкие конструкции, заведите словари вида `alcohol = {0: 'Алкоголь: не указано', 1: 'Алкоголь: жесть как не любит'}`, тогда строковую информацию в коде будете получать просто выбирая элемент из словаря `alcohol[person['alcohol']]`

Comment: Ты лучший, это адская машина заработала и кодик поменьше размером!!

я тебя хочу!!1

БОЖЕ ХРАНИ ПИТОНА И ШОКОЛАДНОГО ЛЕБЕДЯ